# Comparing the output of a getFormElement to a string in CasperJs

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I've been trying to test a webpage to see if a functionality works. The way Im trying to do it is by comparing the output from a getFormValues to a string that it would be if the functionality did work. I wrote the following task to check:

```
casper.then(function seeifsaveworked() {
    if (this.getFormValues('.tf-field-inner') === 'foobar') {
        this.echo("SUCCESS: The site description has been successfully changed, so the save did work", 'INFO');
    } else {
        this.echo("ERROR: The save attempt didn't work successfully, something is wrong with your connection or the page isn't functioning properly.", "ERROR");
        this.die();
    };
});
```

When I run the script, I get a parse error because something about that code isnt syntactically correct. I don't know why it isn't right, and if anyone could possibly troubleshoot the syntax error as well what I would need to do to accomplish the original task that would be absolutely terrific.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the syntax that is incorrect is the semi-colon after the else statement could be a possible error.

```js
casper.then(function seeifsaveworked() {
    if (this.getFormValues('.tf-field-inner') === 'foobar') {
        this.echo("SUCCESS: The site description has been successfully changed, so the save did work", 'INFO');
    } else {
        this.echo("ERROR: The save attempt didn't work successfully, something is wrong with your connection or the page isn't functioning properly.", "ERROR");
        this.die();
    };  <----------- Remove this.
});
```

As for checking the form the documentation for casper shows this:

```js
casper.start('http://www.google.fr/', function() {
    this.fill('form', {q: 'plop'}, false);
    this.echo(this.getFormValues('form').q); // 'plop'
});
```

I think all you have to change is that when you are accessing the form values, you need to specify which field you want to compare and ensure you are selecting the form.

```js
if(this.getFormValues('form#formid').name === 'foobar')...
```

Comment: Awesome, that seems to have resolved the problem! Thanks for the help!